# Log4j2 configuration file in Java EE project

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, log4j2

I have simple `Maven` Java-EE based on `Jersey` web service in my `Eclipse` that runs in Windows 10. Project is created from `jersey-quickstart-webapp` artifact. I'm trying to use `Log4j` logger, but can't find where to place `log4j2.xml` file. I was trying to place it together with source code java files, but logger complains regarding configuration file not found. What is the right place to keep configuration file?

Comment: In a Java EE application you are expected to use the server log method to avoid subtle vendor dependencies. Would that be enough for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it into resources directory. Usually, all configuration files are kept there.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) , Log4j2 will look for the configuration file in the following orders :

> 1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>      ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> 2. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> 5. If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
> 6. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
> 7. If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the
>      classpath.
> 8. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> 9. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
> 10. If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

So you can see that apart from (1) , all are looking the configuration file from classpath . In the standard Maven project , `/src/main/resources` is the root of the classpath .So you can put `log4j2.xml` in `/src/main/resources`.

Otherwise, you have to explicitly specify the configuration file by `log4j.configurationFile` system property :

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```